# Django 1.9 Crispy forms 1.6: multiple forms issue

Tags: python, django, forms, django-crispy-forms

I 'm writing an app in Django 1.9 and installed Crispy forms 1.6 (using bootstrap3 template pack).
In that app, I have a profile model, next to the standard User model.
Now, I want to allow the users to modify their profile, and I want to display both User fields and Profile fields on one page. The Profile model contains an avatar, which I want to display on to of the page, followed by some fields from the User model, and after that the rest of the Profile form's fields.
Something like:

```
> Avatar (Profile model)
> First name (User model)
> Last name (User model)
> E-mail address (User model)
> Street (Profile model)
> ZIP (Profile model)
> Country (Profile model)
> Website (Profile model)
```

I've written 2 Forms:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm)
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm)
```

Both extended with the Crispy forms "FormHelper"

In my template, I render the forms as:
    `{% crispy pform %}` (profile form)
    `{% crispy uform %}` (user form)

But, of course, that does not display the fields as I described earlier.

Does anyone know how I can tackle this problem?

Kind regards!

Wim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you dont create a form as you desire and render fields one by one?

```
<form>
    {{ pform.avatar|as_crispy_field }}
    {{ uform.first_name|as_crispy_field }}
    ...
</form>
```

You may want to initialize forms with different prefixes.

Comment: Because I render them using crispy forms:

Comment: and I want to type as less as possible, but your solution seems to be the only valid one ;-)

Comment: If you want this feature in your project, track down this issue. https://github.com/django-crispy-forms/django-crispy-forms/issues/144#issuecomment-254081034 ,